# How to fix "NoSuchMethodError" in sbt test when going from kafka-client 0.10 to 0.11

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I bumped my version of akka-stream-kafka from 0.11-M2 to 0.17, this also required the kafka-client to bump from 0.9 to 0.11.0 (and scala-lib 2.11.7 to 2.11.8). The code compiles and runs fine (that i know of). However if I run sbt test I get the following error:

```
utils.KafkaUtilSpec *** ABORTED ***
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(Lorg/apache/kafka/common/protocol/SecurityProtocol;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/network/Mode;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/network/LoginType;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/apache/kafka/common/network/ChannelBuilder;
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at kafka.network.Processor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:402)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at kafka.network.SocketServer.newProcessor(SocketServer.scala:140)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at kafka.network.SocketServer$$anonfun$startup$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcVI$sp(SocketServer.scala:93)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at kafka.network.SocketServer$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:92)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at kafka.network.SocketServer$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:88)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:206)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:88)
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [info]   ...
[21:04:04][Step 4/7] [error] Uncaught exception when running utils.KafkaUtilSpec: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(Lorg/apache/kafka/common/protocol/SecurityProtocol;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/network/Mode;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/network/LoginType;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/apache/kafka/common/network/ChannelBuilder;
```

I believe the error was due to the dependency:
    "net.manub" %% "scalatest-embedded-kafka" % "0.7.0" % "test" exclude("log4j", "log4j")
    so I bumped it up to 0.15 and I am now getting this error in sbt test:

```
controllers.v1.MetaDatasetSpec *** ABORTED ***
    [info]   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.server.KafkaServer$.$lessinit$greater$default$2()Lorg/apache/kafka/common/utils/Time;
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$class.startKafka(EmbeddedKafka.scala:465)
    [info]   at controllers.v1.MetaDatasetSpec.startKafka(MetaDatasetSpec.scala:28)
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$$anonfun$withRunningKafka$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(EmbeddedKafka.scala:136)
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$$anonfun$withRunningKafka$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(EmbeddedKafka.scala:135)
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$class.net$manub$embeddedkafka$EmbeddedKafkaSupport$$withTempDir(EmbeddedKafka.scala:187)
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$$anonfun$withRunningKafka$1.apply(EmbeddedKafka.scala:135)
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$$anonfun$withRunningKafka$1.apply(EmbeddedKafka.scala:134)
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$$anonfun$withRunningZooKeeper$1.apply(EmbeddedKafka.scala:177)
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$$anonfun$withRunningZooKeeper$1.apply(EmbeddedKafka.scala:174)
    [info]   at net.manub.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafkaSupport$class.net$manub$embeddedkafka$EmbeddedKafkaSupport$$withTempDir(EmbeddedKafka.scala:187)
    [info]   ...
    [error] Uncaught exception when running controllers.v1.MetaDatasetSpec: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.server.KafkaServer$.$lessinit$greater$default$2()Lorg/apache/kafka/common/utils/Time;
```

I tried changing my "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.9.0.1" exclude("log4j", "log4j"), to 0.11.0 manually in the build.sbt but from sbt evicted it seems Kafka_2.11 stays at 0.9.0.1

Comment: This library is no longer maintained, but that's what you need to upgrade https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka

Comment: I bumped my version from 0.7.0 to 0.15.0 and I recieved the 2nd error above in my post